# How does wait at low priority help to resolve blocking while a shrink (sch-m) has started running (taken the sch-m lock)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

If an existing select query is running, then it takes a sch-s lock.

In this situation, if I run the shrink (which needs sch-m lock) then it will be queued and block subsequent select queries because they need sch-s lock.

Where as if I run shrink with wait at low priority, then it allows the subsequent select queries to run. I get this concept.

However, while a shrink is actively running (after obtaining sch-m lock), then it will block all subsequent select queries. Because select queries need sch-s lock.

The documentation here says (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#understand-concurrency-issues-with-dbcc-shrinkdatabase):

> When attempting to reclaim space during regular usage, shrink database
> and shrink file operations currently require a schema modify lock
> (Sch-M) when moving or deleting Index Allocation Map (IAM) pages,
> blocking the Sch-S locks needed by user queries. As a result,
> long-running queries will block a shrink operation until the queries
> complete. This means that any new queries requiring Sch-S locks are
> also queued behind the waiting shrink operation and will also be
> blocked, further exacerbating this concurrency issue. This can
> significantly impact application query performance and will also cause
> difficulties completing the necessary maintenance to shrink database
> files. Introduced in SQL Server 2022 (16.x), the shrink wait at low
> priority (WLP) feature addresses this problem by taking a schema
> modify lock in WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY mode.

How does wait at low priority allow other select queries to run after the shrink operation is running (that is - after it has taken a sch-m lock)?

Or have I understood the above quote wrong, and shrink with wait at low priorty only allows select to run while shrink is waiting for its chance to run, and that once shrink runs it does not allow selects to run?